# Add Custom index pattern ID to existing Index Pattern

Tags: kibana, kibana-7

I have created an Index Pattern in Kibana, which successfully matches the indexes that I need.  I would like to go back and give that existing Index Pattern a custom ID (In the Advanced Options in Step 2 of the wizard in Kibana when creating).  Is that possible, or do I need to delete/recreate the Index Pattern?

Answer (score 0):

Just for reference how an index pattern looks in the background:

```
{
    "_index" : ".kibana_1",
    "_type" : "_doc",
    "_id" : "index-pattern:metricbeat-*",
    "_score" : 1.0,
    "_source" : {
      "index-pattern" : {
        ...,
        "timeFieldName" : "@timestamp",
        "title" : "metricbeat-*"
      },
      "type" : "index-pattern",
      "references" : [ ],
      "migrationVersion" : {
        "index-pattern" : "6.5.0"
      },
      "updated_at" : "2019-08-11T09:00:09.020Z"
    }
}
```

If you set a custom ID for the index pattern, it will result in `"_id" : "index-pattern:<your-name>"`. So whatever you do, you will need to remove the old index pattern and create a new one (even if you update parts of the document through the API), since the document ID defines the document.

But generally, the index pattern doesn't contain too much information, so it should be easy to recreate, right?

Also, why do you need a specific ID for the index pattern?

Comment: We use the URL in the Discover area of Kibana for some things, which includes id of the index pattern.  By default, its a GUID,  which means if the pattern is deleted/recreated, the URLs would be broken.  If I put a well known value for the ID, we could delete/recreate with the same value, and not break URLs.

Comment: Fair point for that use case. I'm afraid you'll have to recreate the index pattern then (but it should be relatively easy to do)

Comment: @Brian There's an easy way to do that. Creating Index-Pattern in Kibana (which points to some Elastic Index per it's `title` value (sting/regex)) should have a user defined ID (so that you can use to query/delete/create again) without worrying about the alpha-numeric ID which you get if you create such Index-Pattern or even ES index using Kibana's GUI.

Comment: @Brian You can definitely edit an existing Index (ES) /Index-Pattern (Kibana) and change it's ID. Doing so, you need to ensure that any visualization which were using that index-pattern > index, or a dashboard using a visualization > index-pattern > index ... are not broken.